# Average distance to a non-central point in a circle

Tags: calculus, circles

If I pick a point within the circle about the origin of radius $R$, say $(r,\theta) = (0.5 R, \frac{\pi}{2})$, what is the average distance of all other points to that point?

Things which are interesting but not quite what I want:

1. The average distance from the centre of a circle to any point within it is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the radius.
2. If two random points are picked, the average distance is $\dfrac{128 R}{45\pi}$ (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskLinePicking.html)

Comment: A quick [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) may interest you.

Comment: Note that by symmetry the "average distance" you want does not depend on the polar angle $\theta$.

Comment: By "all other points" do you mean points in the disk -- the region surrounded by the circle -- or do you mean points on the circle, i.e. on the boundary of the disk, or do you mean something else?

Comment: In order to post an answer, you must first clarifies your question along the  @MichaelHardy comment.

Comment: Thanks hardmath, yes I suppose the function only depends on the radius. And yes, @Michael Hardy I mean all the points in the disk. Thanks to all for having a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the answer must be given by:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}r\sqrt{a^2+r^2-2ar\cos{\theta}} dr d{\theta}
$$
Where $a$ is the distance of the point from the center, $R$ is the radius of the disc. Wolfram Alfa won't work this out and I haven't the inclination (or maybe ability) to do it myself.

I have done it numerically though, and the result is shown below (where $R=100$). As you can see when $a=0$, we get 66.66 ($\frac{2R}{3}$) as expected.

Within this range it is well approximated with a quadratic.

[image: Average distance to a point within a disc]